# C# Windows Services not make .exe

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2017

I'm new in Visual Studio world and C# programming.
I have to create a simple Windows service but I have a problem during compiling process.
Initially the .exe file was created and I was running by installutil.exe. It works fine (It's simple a very simple program).
Now, I've probably changed some settings in VS and instead of the .exe file I have a DLL. If I use installutil.exe I got error:System.IO.FileNotFoundException.
What settings should I check?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Goto to your project properties and under output type select other than class library

Comment: This is not a answer but more of a recommendation, i would use Topshelf for windows services, its easier to manage and has great documentation.
http://topshelf-project.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed Windows Application from project property. Now it works.